# Python - Making proper list from string

Tags: python, string, list

i have a string like this and i want to make a full list from this string. How can i do that?

`a = "[1,Jhon,5555, R]"`

final result should be like this:

`final_list = [1,"Jhon",5555,"R"]`

Comment: @Carcigenicate: won't work for such a messy input. This needs a more complex parser. Remotely possible, but still: did the OP already attempt anything?

Comment: These are very advanced and I have tried a few of them, it didnt worked . I need an easier and simpler solution. @Carcigenicate

Comment: @snndmnsz why do you have to deal with such a string? What is the source of this?

Comment: Why not just use the same library that produced this to parse this?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga school project.

Comment: @snndmnsz then *presumably* "easier and simpler" means "something acceptable for my school project". In any case that doesn't really answer my question, *what is the source of this data?*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Im appending my data to a csv file and at the same time I have to recall that data in some places, when I recall it the line,  data comes as a string like this "[1,Jhon,5555, R]". I have re-edit data to ue it again.

Comment: @snndmnsz so *you are generating these strings*? The correct solution then is to use a better format (e.g. JSON), instead of just creating something quickly then building a brittle solution to parse it.

Comment: @snndmnsz Please amend your post to include **all** relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Since the input string is valid YAML, you can install [`PyYAML`](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/) and parse the string as YAML:

```
import yaml
a = "[1,Jhon,5555, R]"
final_list = yaml.safe_load(a)
```

`final_list` becomes:

```
[1, 'Jhon', 5555, 'R']
```